# How to transferring my HTML and CSS Code in to a Website so my Uncle have a better business?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, content-management-system, business-process-management

So I created a really cool Website in HTML and CSS for my Uncle because he has a Business, which exists over 30 Years now! and he likes my Design. The Site is just raw in HTML and CSS, so no settings when the screen gets smaller, just raw.

I need a site where i can put my code in. And the Site does the rest. Like make it look appropriate when the screen gets smaller, on a mobile phone or on a tablet.

If there is no way around i could do it by myself, but It would cost me a lot of time, a programm would be so much helpfull, but if necessery I could do it by myown.

Eatherway I need a tailored Site for my needs..

Im 32 and in an 2 Year Full-Time-College-Course to become a Software Developer. We are learning Java right now. But my Uncle wants this site, and I want to deliver, because it would be my first big Site online ;) I'm working with Visual Studio Code, by the way.

So maybe you can give me some helpful Tipps or Input or anything. Wordpress is to prefabricated. I have my onwn Design. Can you recommend something that is more adjusted for my needs??

Just to say this is just a Display Site! No Interaction! No Shop! Nothing! Just for informational Reason, nothing wild.

I hope for new Input, and would be very geatfull for anything.

Thank you for you're Time and have a great Day!

I made a WordPress account, and tried to copy my Design in it or find something nearly my Design, but no success..

Naive me thought I could simply copy my HTML and CSS Code in it. Learned the hard way ;)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) or [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) to deploy a website.

They are both simple to use. Downside of using these is your website will look like https://yourgithubaccount.github.io/yourwebsite or https://yourwebsite.vercel.app